# Getting Dictionary of values from PDF's Internals using iTextSharp and PDFsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I have a project in which I need to split very large PDF files containing between 150 and 200 thousand pages each. I am currently using the iTextSharp DLL to split some of the PDFs which have the "standard" bookmarks that can be created by Adobe Reader. I am also using PDFsharp to extract text from the PDFs that don't have these "standard" bookmarks, whereupon I parse them for keywords from a database and split them into smaller PDFs. As opposed to the first method, however, this is **extremely** slow.

---

The PDFs that don't have the "standard" bookmarks do, however, have indexes/bookmarks. 
The problem is that these are created by SOLindexer([Link to product page](http://www.solimarsystems.com/SOLindexer_Overview.php)). I was able to find these indexes/bookmarks in the internal COS tree. The path within the internal structure of the PDF to the place I want to get to is "trailer/Info/SSEDictionary/Document_MemberStatements".  Within this directory (if it could be called that) I am able to click on -DATA- and open a notepad file which contains all of the account numbers, names, things I need (of course the format is weird, but readable), and I believe that these are the values that I could put in a dictionary.

---

In iTextSharp and PDFsharp you're able to access the Info section by doing, for example, `var stuff = reader.Info.Values` or perhaps `var stuff = reader.Info.Keys`, but those seemed to be dead ends as I could not do anything to get the SSEDictionary contents from there. iTextSharp also allows you to look at the trailer, and I was able to get the keys from there, but past that I could not drill down to the lowest level. I am aware that there is a way to get things from the internals using PDFsharp like so:

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(MapPath("PDFs/Member Statements/06-2012.pdf"), PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly);
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDictionary dictionary = (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDictionary)inputDocument.Internals.Catalog.Elements.GetObject("/Outlines");
```

---

However, I have not been able to figure out how to adapt this to my current situation and the path to the stuff I need.Moreover, I am not quite sure how exactly to do this in iTextSharp (my favorite of the two libraries). Thus, my question would be: how exactly would you get a dictionary (which I believe all of the stuff in the text file I opened up is) in code? Also, what would that code look like? I have a decent understanding of the internal structure of the PDF, but I just don't quite know how to get there. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please replace this wall of text with a short and concise programming related question?

Comment: I thought about that while doing it, but I don't feel like I could explain my situation any more concisely.

Comment: A bit of separation into distinct paragraphs would already help somewhat...

Answer (score 0):

[PDFVole](http://java.net/projects/pdfvole/) is an open source tool based on iText that allows you to navigate through the internal structure of a PDF file. Maybe you can take a look at its source code and get some ideas? If I were you I would start with this one: [PDFTreeParser.java](http://java.net/projects/pdfvole/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/com/btr/pdfvole/PdfTreeParser.java?rev=58)

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't quite get me there. What I'm really interested in is whether or not I can get the data at the bottom of the tree into a dictionary. PDFvole seems to only grab the names of the tree nodes like /Info or /Size, but I still can't get to the bottom. Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: I actually did use it, and I'm able to view the parameters (if they could be called that) that I need. They are called /ACCT_NUMBER and /CUSTOMER_NAME and they are under /SOLIINDEXDICT, however, that doesn't tell me how to actually read those values into a dictionary that I could use.

Comment: It's actually a nice program, I was pleasantly surprised.

Comment: My suggestion was, after running the program and see what it does, to look at the source code of the program so that you can get an idea on how to do the same on your program.

Comment: I looked all over the code and it still hasn't quite gotten me there. Please see my post for more information. http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2090